# Wait answer given amount of time from server

Tags: java, time, request, wait

What should I use to make client wait some time and if after this time he still does not get answer, make request again. If he get answer in specified time continue with other request.

Comment: What kind of request?

Comment: It runs rmi object's method. If the client does not receive any response back, it waits for a predefined amount of time  and submits the same operation request again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do your rmi call on a separate thread and have the main thread wait for a period of time before killing the worker thread and resubmitting the rmi call in case the previous one failed.